# call var in function to outside the function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call this variable outside the function but I get undefined as a result. I understand without var the variable could be called in global scope but i get undefined. I also tried setting the var outside the function and calling it but no success also. Here's my simplified code thank you :)

```
function function1() {
  $.getJSON('random.json')
    .success(successfunction)
    .error(failfunction);

  function successfunction(data) {
    testvar = (data.name);
  }
  function failfunction(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

console.log(testvar);
```

used 
`$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {}`
to load the var after ajax load.

Comment: Where do you call `function1`?

Comment: @ChristianZosel I'll call it in the `function2` to do some math operations and print it in the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want global scope attach your variable to global object like `window`

```
function successfunction(data){
    window.testvar = "var";
}
```

By that you will be sure that it becomes global .

---

However, you should note that `successfunction` is a callback that will be running later on : it is running after timeout & only if the ajax call succeeded .

Comment: I tried with `console.log(testvar);` i'm getting testvar isn't defined.
with `console.log(windows.testvar);` i'm getting undefined :(

edit: yes i can get the data from the json if i call it within the function

Comment: yes but i don't get the whole idea i'm sorry i'm a beginner.

Comment: Ahh now i get it it's because getting the json is taking longer than running the `console.log` i'm getting the `undefined` log right? is there any way i can fire the console.log after the sucess function is called?

edit: used `$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  console.log(window.testvar);
});`

Answer (score 2):

It's just visible in the method scope, you have to declare it outside the function (which means global in this case) or return it in the function call:

```js
var testvar2 = "var 2";

function function1() {
  // parse json
  return successfunction("data");

  function successfunction(data) {
    testvar2 = "var glob";
    var testvar = "var ret";
    return testvar;
  }
  function failfunction(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

console.log(testvar2);
console.log(function1());
console.log(testvar2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Declaring global variables should be avoided and is not good practice, try to define the scope of a variable as small as possible. If any other js module also declares a varibale named `testvar2` funny things might happen.*

Comment: snippet says `test var is not defined` and i'm getting the same result also

Comment: I just get `var 2`, please reload page.

Comment: yes i'm sorry, but i'm trying to get `var` i see you declared it on top of the document so you would get it anyway right? or is there something i don't see? (sorry i'm learning)

Answer (score 1):

try adding a return testvar in suc cessfunction instead of calling testvar

call the successfunction

```
  function successfunction(data){
    testvar = "var";
    return testvar;
}
```